# QCryptographicHash::Sha3_256 differs in Qt5.4 and Qt5.8

Tags: qt, encryption, hash, cryptography, sha

I use `QCryptographicHash::hash(data, QCryptographicHash::Sha3_256).toHex()`
function to encode password `123456` And I get two different results:

```
Qt5.4: c888c9ce9e098d5864d3ded6ebcc140a12142263bace3a23a36f9905f12bd64a 
Qt5.8: d7190eb194ff9494625514b6d178c87f99c5973e28c398969d2233f2960a573e
```

In Qt docs it's said:

> Note: In Qt versions before 5.9, when asked to
>   generate a SHA3 hash sum, QCryptographicHash actually calculated
>   Keccak. If you need compatibility with SHA-3 hashes produced by those
>   versions of Qt, use the Keccak_ enumerators. Alternatively, if source
>   compatibility is required, define the macro QT_SHA3_KECCAK_COMPAT.

But I use Qt5.8 sources from github 5.8 branch! Not 5.9. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably back-ported, after writing the docs for 5.9.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes : I hope you don't mind me running with your idea. At least I upvoted your comment :-)

Comment: TL,DR: It’s a documentation bug.

Comment: @KubaOber: No, OP is using a version that is not officially released (current `HEAD` of branch `5.8`). The official `v5.8.0` release does behave like described in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an online tool like [this one](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha3_256.html) to calculate the SHA3_256 hash of your password and similarly [this one](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html) to calculate the Keccak-256 hash. It shows the exact results that you have displayed in your question.

So [Maarten's remark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52664903/qcryptographichashsha3-256-differs-in-qt5-4-and-qt5-8#comment92264711_52664903) seems correct: the behavior written up in that documentation was at some point introduced into the `5.8` branch. You can see for yourself in the [git history of the file `qcryptographichash.cpp` in the branch called `5.8`](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/commits/5.8/src/corelib/tools/qcryptographichash.cpp) where this happened. You can also see that that was done [after the tag `v5.8.0` was applied](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/v5.8.0/src/corelib/tools/qcryptographichash.h).

So if you switch back to the version that was tagged as `v5.8.0`, you will get the same behavior as you had in `5.4`.

---

Update to respond to your comment.

The mechanism described in the documentation, that is defining the macro `QT_SHA3_KECCAK_COMPAT` to maintain backwards compatibility with older versions, is not backported to `5.8`. Showing the relevant differences between the `5.8` and `5.9` branches (where I trimmed down the output):

```
git difftool -y -x "diff -y -W 72" 5.8 5.9 -- qcryptographichash.h

    enum Algorithm {                        enum Algorithm {
#ifndef QT_CRYPTOGRAPHICHASH_ONL        #ifndef QT_CRYPTOGRAPHICHASH_ONL
        Md4,                                    Md4,
        Md5,                                    Md5,
#endif                                  #endif
        Sha1 = 2,                               Sha1 = 2,
#ifndef QT_CRYPTOGRAPHICHASH_ONL        #ifndef QT_CRYPTOGRAPHICHASH_ONL
        Sha224,                                 Sha224,
        Sha256,                                 Sha256,
        Sha384,                                 Sha384,
        Sha512,                                 Sha512,
        Sha3_224,                  |
        Sha3_256,                  |            Keccak_224 = 7,
        Sha3_384,                  |            Keccak_256,
        Sha3_512                   |            Keccak_384,
                                   >            Keccak_512,
                                   >            RealSha3_224 = 11,
                                   >            RealSha3_256,
                                   >            RealSha3_384,
                                   >            RealSha3_512,
                                   >    #  ifndef QT_SHA3_KECCAK_COMPAT
                                   >            Sha3_224 = RealSha3_224,
                                   >            Sha3_256 = RealSha3_256,
                                   >            Sha3_384 = RealSha3_384,
                                   >            Sha3_512 = RealSha3_512
                                   >    #  else
                                   >            Sha3_224 = Keccak_224,
                                   >            Sha3_256 = Keccak_256,
                                   >            Sha3_384 = Keccak_384,
                                   >            Sha3_512 = Keccak_512
                                   >    #  endif
#endif                                  #endif
    };                                      };
```

As you can see, the macro `QT_SHA3_KECCAK_COMPAT` only has a meaning in `5.9`.

Comment: Looks like branch 5.8 (at HEAD) has no Keccak at all, and code for it can't be made compatible with code written for 5.4.

Comment: @ephemerr: you are correct, I added an update to my answer. If you need compatibility with `5.4`, you will have to stick with `v5.8.0` or change the `Qt` source code for `5.8` or upgrade to `5.9` and use `QT_SHA3_KECCAK_COMPAT`.